# Android: PlaceAutomcompleteFragment working but not going off after its usage

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-places-api

In my activity, I am using PlaceAutoCompleteFragment. I have defined it in the main Layout XML. Once the Use of placeautocoplete fragment is done. I am not able to get it off the view.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.jawadh.startthreeproject.MapsActivity" />
    <fragment
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
        />
</FrameLayout >
```

This is my Activity code:

```
final PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);

    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {

        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            String placeDetailsStr = place.getName() + "\n"
                    + place.getId() + "\n"
                    + place.getLatLng().toString() + "\n"
                    + place.getAddress() + "\n"
                    + place.getAttributions();

            m.setPosition(place.getLatLng());
            m.setTitle(place.getName().toString());


mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(place.getLatLng()));
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(place.getLatLng(), 17.0f));

              }

            public void onError(Status status) {
                // TODO: Handle the error.
                //   Log.i(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
            }
        });

        }
```

So Once the OnPlaceSelectedListener finishes i want to just destroy the fragment or take it off the view. It is causing hindrance to ehatever  add to the view. Making a new layout xml will also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the fragment at `onDestroyView()`

```
@Override 
public void onDestroyView() { 
     super.onDestroyView();
     FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
     FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
     ft.remove(autocompleteFragment).commit();
}
```